# hide label text witout hiding checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to toggle label text into input, this is my code:

```
<label id="text-1" class="todo-text">adasdsad<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="todo-checkbox" onclick="handleCheck('text-1', 'checkbox-1')"></label>
```

logging this will log only the text without the checkbox:

```
const dataval = dataContainer.firstElementChild.innerText
console.log('dataval  ', dataval)
```

but when i do:

```
dataContainer.firstElementChild.innerText = ''
```

checkbox is also removed. help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the first textNode using [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) property and then update the text content by updating [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) property of the text node.

```
dataContainer.firstElementChild.firstChild.nodeValue = '';
```

```js
const dataContainer = document.getElementById('div');

const dataval = dataContainer.firstElementChild.innerText
console.log('dataval  ', dataval)

dataContainer.firstElementChild.firstChild.nodeValue = '';
```

```html
<div id="div">
<label id="text-1" class="todo-text">adasdsad<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="todo-checkbox" onclick="handleCheck('text-1', 'checkbox-1')"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping the entire label and checkbox in the `label` tag. Just wrap the label in the `label` tag.

```
<label id="text-1" class="todo-text">adasdsad</label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="todo-checkbox" onclick="handleCheck('text-1', 'checkbox-1')">
```

Example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/7oucg6jh/